# xpath: check if element is within other element

Tags: xpath

I have quite a large XML structure that in its simplest form looks kinda like this:

```
<document>
    <body>
        <section>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </section>
    </body>
    <backm>
        <section>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <figure><title>This</title></figure>
        </section>
    </backm>
</document>
```

The `section` levels can be almost limitless (both within the `body` and `backm` elements) so I can have a `section` in `section` in `section` in `section`, etc. and the `figure` element can be within a `numlist`, an `itenmlist`, a `p`, and a lot more elements.

What I want to do is to check if the `title` in `figure` element is somewhere within the `backm` element. Is this possible?

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: You want to tell whether it's anywhere within the text of `backm`?

Comment: Homer6: i have tried /body/backm[*::this] and with variations on levels, but there are to many levels to cover every possible alternative so i need a more general solution.

Comment: harpo: i want to tell whether the title in figure element is anywhere within the backm-element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document could have multiple `<backm>` elements and it could have multiple `<figure><title>Title</title></figure>` elements in it. How you build your query depends on the situations you're trying to distinguish between.

```
//backm/descendant::figure/title
```

Will return the `<title>` elements that are the child of a `<figure>` element and the descendant of a `<backm>` element.

So:

```
count(//backm/descendant::figure/title) > 0
```

Will return `True` if there are 1 or more such `title` elements.

---

You can also express this using [Double Negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)

```
not(//backm[not(descendant::figure/title)])
```

I'm under the impression that this should have better performance.

---

```
//title[parent::figure][ancestor::backm]
```

Lists all `<title>` elements with a parent of `<figure>` and an `<backm>` ancestor.

Comment: MattH: Thanks for the reply! Some clarifications: there can only be one backm. And i want to check IF the title in figure element is within the backm element.

Comment: @user2075124: You're welcome. I'm still trying to wrap my head around double negatives in `xpath`, I kind of understand them one moment and then lose it the next!

Comment: Yeah, double negatives are tricky. Doesnt work though (only checks IF there is a title in figure in backm, i want to check if the current title in figure IS within a backm).

Comment: @user2075124: That isn't what you asked for.

Comment: Well, english isn't my native language so i appologize for any confusion. I tried to be clear by writing: "What I want to do is to check if the title in figure element is somewhere within the backm element. Is this possible"

Comment: @user2075124: see update I assume you can reapply those predicates to the "current title".

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Worked like a charm!